# “ error: "The parameter 'map.net.xml' is not allowed in this context" , when I want to create " .poly.xml" file” in sumo

Tags: omnet++, sumo

I have a question about the polyconvert while I was importing a map
from Openstreetmap.

I successfully completed the netconvert commnad and try to get a map.poly

After I execute command:

```
polyconvert --net-file map.net.xml --osm-files map.osm
--type-file typemap.xml -o map.poly.xml
```

after that show these errors:

> Error: The parameter 'map.net.xml' is not allowed in this context. 
>   Switch or parameter name expected.
>
> Error: Could not parse commandline options. Quitting (on error).

please help me solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: The call looks perfectly fine. Which sumo version do you use?

Comment: I downloaded the map again from the OpenStreetMap and my problem was fixed